# Digital signature in iTextSharp

Tags: c#, digital-certificate

Following code is used to create .ts file from pdf. It has use web service for time stamp.
Class DigitalSignature{

```
    public void OpenPdf(string path)
    {


        try
        {

            byte[] bytData = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
            SHA256Managed sha = new SHA256Managed();
            byte[] hash = sha.ComputeHash(bytData);
            mk.kibs.wstsatest.wsTSATest oWS = new mk.kibs.wstsatest.wsTSATest();

            //  X509Store Store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
            var Store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
            Store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            X509Certificate2Collection Col = Store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByIssuerName, "KIBS", true);
            oWS.Url = Settings.Default.DigitalSignature_mk_kibs_wstsatest_wsTSATest;
            if (Col.Count > 0)
            {

                oWS.ClientCertificates.Add(Col[0]);
            }

                mk.kibs.wstsatest.TSResponse_Bytes resp = oWS.funGenerateTS_Bytes(hash);
                string strFailureInfo = resp.strFailureInfo;
                byte[] byTimeStamped = resp.bytTSToken;
                oWS.Dispose();
                if (strFailureInfo == string.Empty)
                {
                    File.WriteAllBytes(path +".ts"+ byTimeStamped);

                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(strFailureInfo);
                }
            }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }          

    }
```

I succeed to generate .ts from pdf file with code above. Any suggestion how to generate a digitally signed file from ts. ?

Comment: *how to generate a digitally signed file from ts* - what do you mean? You have externally time stamped a file. Thus, you have a time stamped file, not a digitally signed file.

Comment: Yes, With given .pfx certificate i need to generate .ts file then use it to generate digital signature.

Comment: *With given .pfx certificate i need to generate .ts file then use it to generate digital signature.* - That is very unclear. Do you mean that you want to create a detached signature of your file (which happens to be a PDF) with your time stamp embedded as a signed document time stamp attribute? If yes, what kind of signature? Any special profile? If no, what *do* you mean?

Comment: Yes, that's main problem.

Comment: Ok, if you really want to create a detached signature (i.e. a signature in a separate file and not an integrated PDF signature), this is not a question of iTextSharp usage. You need iTextSharp (or a comparable general purpose PDF library) to create integrated PDF signatures; for external, detached signatures you only need .Net or BouncyCastle security libraries.